# Apache-pig not running in local mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, data-analysis

I have set up pig but i am getting this error

```
**pig -x local Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.pig.Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.Main**
```

pig version --pig-0.17.0.tar.gz
I have setup all the Envirnment Variables

I was expecting that it would open grunt shell
I have tried verifing the path and other envirnment variables like JAVA_HOME and PIG_HOME.I have verified all the paths in pig.cmd